# paper-input multiline rows="3" issue when inside core-animated-pages

Tags: polymer

I have stumbled upon polymer and started making a small web-application. I started encountering an issue when using paper-input with multiline and rows attributes as a descedant to core-animated-pages. To check whether its occurring due to some configuration problems, I downloaded the topeka app (http://www.polymer-project.org/apps/topeka/) and changed the last name to

```
<paper-input multiline rows="5" label="Last Initial" id="last" maxlength="1"></paper-input>
```

and the error persisted. So I am assuming its a bug in the implementation. Can some one clarify the same?

I have provided the link to modified topeka app with issue here - http://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/~ee10b020/Developer/topeka-master/

Comment: what is the issue ? can you post a screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. We fixed it by calling the rowsChanged function of the paper-input Element within domReady of our Polymer element which ist included in core-animated-pages.

```
Polymer("YOURELEMENT", {
      domReady: function(){
           this.$.last.rowsChanged();
      }
});
```

Problem is that rowsChanged is called but because of core-animated-pages the paper-input element isn't present in dom.

Comment: Its seems to working on console when I select the element and do $0.rowsChanged() but when I do what you have recommended i.e call this.$.last.rowsChanged() inside domReady, its not working as expected for some reason!

Comment: I had a look at your app and debugged the line in Chrome. We make the call in the same way. But in your app, the domReady of your topeka-profile is fired before showing the element

Comment: of course it's called before showing, but in our case the function gets the height of the helper-element (inputClone) at this time and in your case the height is 0px at this time.